# Small issue with the way I should call several plug-in for ember-cli-jstree

Tags: javascript, ember.js, plugins, ember-cli, jstree

as the title say I have a small problem. I can't figure out how to call multiple plug-in of [ember-cli-jstree](https://github.com/ritesh83/ember-cli-jstree). Right now, I have that

```js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    "plugins" : "dnd",
    data: 
      [...],
});
```

Here, I can use the plug-in **drag and drop**, but if I want to use several plug-in, how should I write it?
 I already tried:

```js
    "plugins" : "dnd", "type",
    "plugins" : {"dnd", "type"},
    "plugins" : ["dnd", "type"],
    "plugins" : "dnd" + "type",
```

Maybe I'm dumb or something, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, you have to write it like that:

```js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    "plugins" : "dnd, types",
    data: 
      [...],
});
```